# Is deciding whether the language of a TM contains all strings of length 4 computable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I was going through some Halting Problem reduction and I found the following problem:

> Given a semi-decider TM $M$, does the language $L(M)$ contain all strings of exactly length $4$?

The question later asks to prove whether this is recursive or r.e. Going through some practicing, I came to the conclusion that this is must be r.e., since otherwise such problem would solve the Halting Problem.

So, I attempted this question by showing that $$HP < 4LENGTH$$

My approach is to show that $4LENGTH$ is recursive and then showing the contraddiction, that $HP$ is not recursive, so is $4LENGTH$.

However I can't understand how to construct such machine. Moreover, by looking at some similar proof I see that they suggest to build a machine $M'$ that erases the tape, writes $I$ (input) on the tape and simulate $M$. However, I can't follow such proof.

Can someone describe how to solve such problem or give any direction?

Comment: So? Everybody makes mistakes. Anyway, I think I figured out the correct parenthesisation (I think). Note that "this is must be r.e., since otherwise such problem would solve the Halting Problem" is not a meaningful statement; every recursive language is *also* recursively enumerable.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. So please tell me if I am wrong, but by saying that I thought I meant that we can accept, but never reject.

Comment: That's too strong; even for a language $L$ in RE - R (the languages that are rec. enumerable but not recursive), there may be a TM that can reject infinitely many strings from $\overline{L}$ -- just not *all*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help you understand a standard proof technique for such problems. An instance of HP is a pair, $(\langle M\rangle, x)$ where $\langle M\rangle$ is a description of a TM $M$ and $x$ is a string. To reduce HP to 4LENGTH we require a function $f$ that maps instances of HP to instances of 4LENGTH such that $(\langle M\rangle, x)\in HP\Longleftrightarrow f((\langle M\rangle, x))\in 4LENGTH$. In other words, an instance $I = (\langle M\rangle, x)$ will have a "yes" answer ($M$ halts on $x$) if and only if the transformed instance will have a "yes" answer ($f(I)$ accepts all strings of length 4).

Given $(\langle M\rangle, x)$, we'll define a TM $M'$, using $M$ and $x$, that acts as follows:

```
M'(y) =
   if |y| = 4
      erase y
      write x on the tape
      simulate M
      return accept
```

Now if $(\langle M\rangle, x)\in HP$, then $M$ will halt on $x$ and so $M'$ will accept any string of length 4, so $M'\in 4LENGTH$.

On the other hand, if $(\langle M\rangle, x)\notin HP$, then $M$ will never halt on $x$ and so $M'$ will never get to the `return accept` statement and so will accept nothing. Hence if $(\langle M\rangle, x)\notin HP$, then $M'\notin4LENGTH$.

To summarize, we have established a faithful mapping from instances of HP to instances of 4LENGTH.

---

Now to show that 4LENGTH is not recursive, we argue by contradiction. Suppose that 4LENGTH were recursive. Then there would be a decider, $D_4$, for 4LENGTH namely, given any TM description $\langle N \rangle$, $D_4$ would take that description as input and halt and either return "yes" if $\langle N \rangle\in 4LENGTH$ and "no" if $\langle N \rangle\notin 4LENGTH$.

We can then use $f$ and $D_4$ to build a decider for HP. It would work like this:

1. Given an instance $I=(\langle M\rangle, x)$ of HP, use $f$ to produce an instance $f(I)=\langle N\rangle$ of 4LENGTH.
2. Run the decider $D_4$ on $f(I)$.
3. If $D_4$ answers "yes" to $f(I)$, then by the construction of $f$, $I$ must have been in HP. Similarly, if $D_4$ answers "no", $I$ must not have been in HP. In short, we've built a decider for HP, contradicting the fact that HP is not recursive.

Comment: I can't understand why we erase y, can you tell more about that?

Comment: @revisingcomplexity. Just so that you can clear the deck for the simulation of $M$ on $x$. It's not that important of a point.

Comment: Why do we use the HP as decider for 4Length? Should it not be the other way around since HP < 4LENGTH ? (I might have understood it wrongly!)

Comment: @revisingcomplexity. We're using a decider for 4LENGTH to construct a decider for HP. See if my revised description is any clearer. This construction is, as I said, common, but you're in the same boat as many of my students: the first time you see it, it can be hard to grasp. Keep at it--eventually it will make sense.